# Listen Event for Any Object in a Table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Another newbie query. Now on my third day of working with Corona.

The following code works fine: Balloons are generated and float into the air. Now I want to use :addEventListener( "tap", pushBalloon ) to make it so that when a balloon is clicked the pushBalloon is executed. Can anyone tell me what variable I would use and how I would define it? And also I guess I would have to change the pushBalloon function too for the new variable.

Thank you.

```
local function createBalloon()
local randomBalloon = math.random( 10 )


    local newBalloon = display.newImageRect( objectSheet, randomBalloon, 112, 142 )
    table.insert( balloonsTable, newBalloon )
    physics.addBody( newBalloon, "dynamic", { radius=70, bounce=0 } )
    newBalloon.myName = "bigBalloon"
newBalloon.alpha = 0.75
newBalloon.gravityScale = randomBalloon/-150

local whereFrom = math.random( 3 )

    if ( whereFrom == 1 ) then
        -- From the left
        newBalloon.x = 100
        newBalloon.y = display.contentHeight+150

    elseif ( whereFrom == 2 ) then
        -- From the top
        newBalloon.x = 160
        newBalloon.y = display.contentHeight+150
    elseif ( whereFrom == 3 ) then
        -- From the right
        newBalloon.x = 220
        newBalloon.y = display.contentHeight+150

end
end

local function gameLoop()
    -- Create new balloon
    createBalloon()
     -- Remove balloons which have drifted off screen
    for i = #balloonsTable, 1, -1 do
     local thisBalloon = balloonsTable[i]

        if ( thisBalloon.x < -100 or
             thisBalloon.x > display.contentWidth + 100 or
             thisBalloon.y < -100  )
        then
            display.remove( thisBalloon )
            table.remove( balloonsTable, i )
        end

    end

end



local function pushBalloon()
    --  balloon:applyLinearImpulse( 0.2, -2, balloon.x, balloon.y )
    -- tapCount = tapCount + 1
    -- tapText.text = tapCount
     newBalloon.gravityScale = 10

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `newBalloon` objects to a table, but you should add the event listener to each `newBalloon` DisplayObject as it is instantiated.  This doesn't do exactly what you ask in the title (where simply inserting an object into a table would effectively add an event listener to that object), but achieves the event response I think you are looking for.

If you are tapping the balloon, you would put the listener on the balloon. If you use a "tap" event, the `target` property tells you which object was touched, so your `pushBalloon()` function works for any balloon.

```
local pushBalloon( event )
   local balloon = event.target

   if event.phase == "began"

       -- do something to the balloon object (apply impulse, etc.)

   end

end


local function createBalloon()
    ...
    local newBalloon = display.newImageRect( ... )

    if newBalloon then

        -- set properties of DisplayObject and add event listener

        newBallon:addEventListener( "tap", pushBalloon )

    end
    ...
end
```

I have wrapped the call to `addEventListener()` in a check to make sure `newBalloon ~= nil`.

Comment: Thank you. I have made the changes you made suggested and I am getting the error "addEventListener: listener cannot be nil." Urg I have no idea how to show you to code changes I have made on here. Do I edit my original post or make a new post?? Thank you so much for you rhelp.

Comment: I'm pretty to all this as well.  I think you should post a new question (in fact, it seems [you already have](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42909655/6286781)) with the new code as that error message is not related to this question about adding event listeners.